# Changing font-awesome size in css. How do you do it?

Tags: font-awesome

I tried changing font awesome sizes using font-size but it doesn't work because of this css:

```
font-size: inherit
```

Is there a way to override this? I am trying to have font-awesome to be two different sizes when mobile or screen and I want to affect the font-size using css and not different sized font-awesome tags. What can I do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually font-awesome icons get the size of the element they are used within (i.e. inherit). For example:

HTML

```
<p><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Some text here.</p>
```

CSS

```
p{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Your icon will be of 16px size in that case.
However you can resize icons separately. First of all, make sure that your css file goes after font-awesome.css in `<head>` block for it to be in priopity or use !important.

1) You can rewrite 'fa' class styles from font-awesome.css in your own css file:

```
.fa{
    font-size: 3em !important; /*size whatever you like*/
}
```

2) Or give icon some other class and style it:

```
.newclass-for-i{
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

To set different styles for mobile and screen use css media queries:

```
@media (max-width:desired width){
    your styles
}
```

Answer (score 3):

font awesome has classes for size such as fa-2x, fa-3x etc...

For example:

```
<i class="fas fa-user fa-2x">
```

Comment: Here is a link to the docs: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/size

Answer (score 2):

You can update the font-size of a FA icon using the before pseudo-element. No need for extra wrapper elements or rewriting classes.

```
i.fa::before{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an extra class or id e.g.

```
<i class="fa fa-search large_icon"></i>
```

and the style it using css

```
.large_icon{
   font-size:24pt;
}
```